# Kue - TypeError: Cannot read property 'zcard' of null

Tags: node.js, redis, kue

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'zcard' of null
    at Queue.card (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/kue/lib/kue.js:513:14)
    at Queue.inactiveCount (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/kue/lib/kue.js:616:17)
    at _ (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/kue/lib/http/routes/json.js:318:19)
    at exports.stats (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/kue/lib/http/routes/json.js:41:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at /Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/kue/lib/http/middleware/provides.js:11:36
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/send/index.js:245:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/send/index.js:356:12)
    at next (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/send/index.js:630:16)
    at onstat (/Users/narain/Sites/integrity-automation/node_modules/send/index.js:619:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

I 'm getting this error pretty consistently under the following conditions:

1. Have kui-ui dashboard open in a browser window
2. perform graceful shutdown

I'm not certain if it is expected for `Queue.client` to be null. If it is, then `Queue.prototype.card` should first check if `this.client` exists before calling `this.client.card`. Same with `Queue.prototype.cardByType`

Here's my api route `dashboard/stop` code (i.e., stops the process and flush the cache):

```
exports.stop = function(success, failure) {

  let shutdown = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    debug('shutting down queue');
    queue.shutdown().then(() => {
      client.flushdb(); // flushing the redis server
      debug('redis is flushed');
      resolve({success: true});
    },
    (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });

  return shutdown;

};
```

Note: `queue` is an instance of `Kue` and `client` is of `redis`:

```
let queue = require('kue').createQueue({prefix: '', redis: config.get('redisurl'), jobEvents: false});

let client = require('redis').createClient({
  'url': config.get('redis') // redis-url
});
```

Same question (issue) have also been raised on github:

1. https://github.com/Automattic/kue/issues/825
2. https://github.com/StreetHub/kue-ui/issues/23

And have no response yet..

Any Idea/thoughts! How to get this fix..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was causing because of `Queue.prototype.shutdown` implementation destroy client (i.e., redis) instance that's why when it call `Queue.prototype.card`and `Queue.prototype.cardByType` then it throws that error..

As for as my aim was to somehow stop (pause) the queue process and then resume it again.. so i have done something like that instead of using `Queue.prototype.shutdown` i have rather used `Worker.prototype.shutdown` which pauses the worker's (process)..

`queue.js` (sample):

```
this.queue = kue.createQueue({prefix: opts.prefix, redis: opts.redis, jobEvents: false, disableSearch: false}); // kue instance

stopAllWorkers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var length = this.queue.workers.length;
      this.queue.workers.forEach((worker) => {
        worker.shutdown(() => {
          if (--length === 0) {
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

`serverRunner.js` (sample):

```
var queue = require('./queue');

exports.start = function(success, failure) {
    // resume the queue process
}

exports.stop = function(success, failure) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    queue.removeAllListeners();
    queue.stopAllWorkers().then(() => {
      debug('Queue All workers stopped!!');
      resolve({success: true});
    });
  });
};
```

That's it!

Hope this help others!!

Cheers.